# linux - List partition labels of partitions residing inside a raw IMG file without mounting the IMG file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xubuntu

I have a multi-partitioned IMG raw disk file and I want to list the partition labels of each partition without mounting it.

The command `fdisk -l` nearly works as I want but does not list the labels:

```
fdisk -l test.img
Disk test.img: 200 MiB, 209715200 bytes, 409600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xcae9ed5b

Device     Boot  Start    End Sectors Size Id Type
test.img1  *      2048 104447  102400  50M  b W95 FAT32
test.img2       104448 206847  102400  50M  b W95 FAT32
test.img3       206848 309247  102400  50M  b W95 FAT32
test.img4       309248 409599  100352  49M  5 Extended
test.img5       311296 409599   98304  48M  b W95 FAT32
```

The reason I want this is so that I know which one to mount. The above is just an example of a sample raw disk file that I created for testing purposes but the real one is a 128GB UFD with many different partitions - being used as a multi-boot drive.

Is something like disk possible? So far I have only been able to list labels after I mount the partition but that defeats the purpose. Having so many partitions, I want to see each partition label as part of the output shown above or by using any other command if possible so I know which one is which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how to *easily* do this without the system's help, as root. It's possible to ask the system to make the partitions known, then ask it again informations about partitions and filesystems within. Here "the system" is a loose combination of kernel features and udev built-in detection features. Only those two commands are needed: [`kpartx`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/kpartx.8.html) and [`blkid`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/blkid.8.html). My example has different values than OP's example but is quite similar:

```
# kpartx -v -a test.img 
add map loop0p1 (253:8): 0 20480 linear 7:0 2048
add map loop0p2 (253:9): 0 22528 linear 7:0 22528
add map loop0p3 (253:10): 0 20480 linear 7:0 45056
add map loop0p4 (253:11): 0 2 linear 7:0 65536
add map loop0p5 (253:12): 0 40960 linear 7:0 67584

# blkid /dev/loop0 /dev/mapper/loop0p*
/dev/loop0: PTUUID="a5ebeec3" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/mapper/loop0p1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="MYFS1" UUID="D816-AFC1" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="a5ebeec3-01"
/dev/mapper/loop0p2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="MYFS2" UUID="D857-D702" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="a5ebeec3-02"
/dev/mapper/loop0p3: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="MYFS3" UUID="D894-3506" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="a5ebeec3-03"
/dev/mapper/loop0p4: PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="a5ebeec3-04"
/dev/mapper/loop0p5: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="MYLASTFS" UUID="074A-2F0F" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="a5ebeec3-05"

# kpartx -v -d test.img 
del devmap : loop0p5
del devmap : loop0p4
del devmap : loop0p3
del devmap : loop0p2
del devmap : loop0p1
loop deleted : /dev/loop0
```

The filesystems weren't mounted. Only the partitions were mapped, examined, and unmapped.

Comment: Well done! Thank you. Although it's not an easy way, it still tells us the label of each partition. I have accepted this answer as I don't expect an easier way than this.